# Javascript how do I change javascript array format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel

I am creating a file upload operation where I'll retrieve content of file and perform some function with them.

I ask users to enter data in the format below in an excel sheet and save the excel file as a CSV file.

[image]
 Then I use this function to read an display the file content.

```
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv");

      readFile = function () {

              console.log("file uploaded");
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function () {
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
            };
            }
            if (fileInput){
                fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);
            }
```

the function output this image. [image]

what I have not been able to figure out is how do I convert and arrange from the file output format to the desired output format.

var numbers = [75799757,9744710,79989647,99029704,];

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z39ntvfp/

Comment: @JagadeshaNH the initial out array does not include commas just spaces in between them. arr without the comma.

Comment: Then remove comma in append

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbers = [75799757,9744710,79989647,99029704];
var str="";

numbers.forEach(function(number){
 str += number + ", ";
});

var newStr = str.substring(0, str.length-2);

document.write(newStr);
```